# hibernate hql getMaxVersion

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table with the following structure:

> ReportId
>  Version
>  Title
>  .....

I want to use HQL to fetch the newest version of the report by id. Would the following query work?

```
from Report where reportId = :reportId and version = (select max(version) from Report where reportId = :reportId)
```

Is it possible to retrieve the row with the maximum version without using a sub-select? Is the above sub-select even legal in hibernate HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
    from Report where reportId = :reportId order by version desc
```

with setMaxResults=1

Comment: This covers 99% of the use cases, but what if I want to retrieve a list of titles for ALL of the reports? For example, a drop-down menu with the titles of ALL reports which can be produced by the system....

Comment: SELECT reportId, title, max(version)  FROM report GROUP BY reportId. But you have to use projections in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by version and use setMaxResults on the query (set it to 1). As for the other question, subselects like this are legal in hql.